# Test IP reachability with ERRORLEVEL of ping.exe

Tags: batch-file, ping

### Background

- I want to check whether a specified host is IP reachable before some operation in `.bat` file.
- I tried using `ping.exe` to test IP reachability, but I found `ping.exe` returns ERRORLEVEL 0 when the specified host is IP reachable or the network is unreachable.

### Question

How can I test IP reachability of a specified host in `.bat` file?

Is there any way to distinguish IP reachable and network unreachable with `ping.exe`, or any other command to test IP reachability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use also use a structure similar to this, *(I've used an `Echo` command upon success)*:

```dos
Ping -n 1 151.141.90.381 | Find "TTL=" >Nul && Echo host is reachable
```

…or more likely in your case, *(this would end the script if the host was not reachable and any commands you would lke to run would follow that line)*:

```dos
Ping -n 1 151.141.90.381 | Find "TTL=" >Nul || GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Errorlevel of `ping` is not reliable (as you have noticed). (ab)use `find`to get an errorlevel

```
ping 192.168.0.99 | find "TTL="
echo %errorlevel%
```

(Note: searching for `TTL=` is the most reliable solution)