# IP address for testing "host not found" and "network unreachable" case

Tags: batch-file, ping

### Background

- I am making a `.bat` file work with remote hosts.
- This `.bat` file [uses `ping` to test IP reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928636/).
- I want to test the behavior of this script.

  - For nominal scinarios, I can use localhost.
  - For non-nominal scinarios, I tried using IP address reserved for documentation (e.g. `192.0.2.1`), but `ping` command returned `Request timed out` rather than `Destination host unreachable`.

### Question

Is there any IP address that always returns `Destination host unreachable` and `Destination net unreachable` ?

### Edit

For example, when my IP is `192.168.1.2/24`, I might be able to use `ping 192.168.1.100` for `Destination host unreachable` scinario.
But this test will fail if `192.168.1.100` is leased with DHCP. Also this test will fail if my IP is `10.1.1.2/24`.
I want to make all the tests successful in any environments.

### Edit 2

- This `.bat` file work with `.xlsx` files on remote hosts. Excel 2010 has a defect on handling of files in unauthenticated shared directories (Excel will hang with them), so I want to make sure the remote host is IP reachable and the target path is accessible.
- To check IP reachability, this `.bat` file [uses `ping.exe` to test IP reachability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47928636/). I think users of this `.bat` file can use the result of `ping.exe` to break down the problem.

  - For example, if `ping.exe` returns `Destination host unreachable` and it worked properly in yesterday, the remote host was shutted down or freezed.
  - Or if `ping.exe` returns `Destination net unreachable` and it worked properly in another network, the problem will be on the network, not the remote host.
- The behavior of `ping.exe` is different according to IP reachability.

  - In IP reachable case (This is a nominal scinario), `ERRORLEVEL` of `ping.exe` will be `0` and the output will contain `TTL=`.
  - In `Destination host unreachable` case (This is a non-nominal scinario), `ERRORLEVEL` of `ping.exe` will be `1`.
  - In `Destination net unreachable` case (This is another non-nominal scinario), `ERRORLEVEL` of `ping.exe` will be `0` and the output will not contain `TTL=`.
- I want to test the handling of the results of `ping.exe` on these three scenarios.

  - To IP reachable case, I can use localhost as the target IP address.
  - To `Destination host unreachable` case, I might be able to use an unallocated IP address on the same subnet. But such test will fail if the target IP address is leased with DHCP, or the test environment is moved to another subnet. I want to make all the tests successful in any environments.
  - This is the same with `Destination host unreachable` case.

Comment: I don't believe there are any designated IP address that always won't be reachable or absent in the global DNS system.  What you can do is pick a couple local IP addresses that meet your requirements.  Have you got access to your DHCP server configuration?  What's the address range?  Are they all assigned? You'd also need access to your local DNS server or barring that, your system hosts file.

Comment: there are sites, that don't respond to `ping` (Responding to `ping` is a special service, that can be disabled). www.microsoft.com is (currently) one of them. There is no guarantee, they don't change it in the future.

Comment: `ping 192.0.2.1` works fine here and says `Request timed out.`. This is a alternative way to ping `wmic path win32_pingstatus where address="192.0.1.2" get /format:list`

Comment: I Fixed the question. Actually, as you said, `ping 192.0.2.1` returned `Request timed out`.

Comment: I add some background to the question. I can pick some IP address for tests, but the result of these tests will deeply depend on environment. I want to make all the tests successful in any environment.

Answer (score 0):

If no result is returned, there is no way of knowing whether the address was reachable or non existent, because both are not reachable.

If you send out a ping and the response is unanswered, how are you supposed to know why? It may not have been answered because the intended host no longer exists but the host or DN servers may have technical issues. Unless the respective servers have some form of auto response setup informing the pinger of the reason why they're not responding, all you will know is that they're not reachable, *(and and auto response is still a response)*.

"The host timed out" only informs you that a response didn't return within a specific response period, not of a reason why!

Comment: you answered a different question.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: I removed the almost repeated response from my answer, but the rest currently remains because the OP isn't clear what they are trying to determine, or what their nominal and non nominal scenarios are. `Ping` determines only whether or not a response was returned within a specific time period. If something other than reachable or unreachable is required then `ping` isn't what I would select as the appropriate tool.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added some background information to the question. `Ping.exe` can distinguish `host unreachable` case and `net unreachable` case, so I think it can be used to break down the problem. I also think it is important that `Ping.exe` is only a tool that can be used even in the default Windows installation.